# Remove the zero infront of a TIME function retrieved from a database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, pastebin

Okay so in my data base i have the following columns: `id`, `title`, `admission`, `date_start`, `date_end`, `time_start`, `time_end`, `location`, `description`, `image`, `hyperlink`

I am retrieving `date_start` and `date_end` from the data base and I have cleaned up the data some, but have not been able to remove the 0 before the dates.

My code so far: http://pastebin.com/eAUXtkaX

The output of the `date_start` and `date_end` function is:

Date Start:   December 04 - 6  // This is for when two different days are entered into the db

Date Start:   December 25       //This is for when two days entered are displayed as the same.

Okay so on the one that is for when two different days are entered into the database, how would i remove the 0 before the first digit?

MySQL Query(Also in the pastebin):

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(date_start, '%M %d'),
(IF(date_start = date_end,'',CONCAT(' - ', DAY(date_end))))) newDate 
FROM events3 
WHERE date_end >= CURDATE() 
ORDER BY date_start LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Use `%e` instead of `%d` in your `date_format` query

Comment: You should not post (well, not even post, *link*) your complete application code just to ask how to format a number. You need to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `ltrim()` function?

Assuming that the date that you want to strip the `0` of is `$date` ..

```
$date = ltrim($date, '0');
```

Read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php)

If I'm not mistaken, you should replace

```
$date_start = $rows['date_start'];
$date_end = $rows['date_end'];
```

With

```
$date_start = ltrim($rows['date_start'], '0');
$date_end = ltrim($rows['date_end'], '0');
```

Comment: `$date` would be the string that you are trying to strip the `0` from.

Comment: That shouldn't be a comment on my answer, the two are not related. @user1876032 - Please see my update (:

Comment: Thanks for that it worked. I used both the %e and the date_format